# Windows + OpenServer + SSL

Tags: windows, https, openserver, openssl

Добрый день, запустил сайт на своем ПК , дал доступ по портам 80 и 443 для общего доступа, установил ssl сертификаты, все работает на других машинах, однако со своего локального, сайт открыть не могу. Подскажите как мне решить эту проблему.
Как веб сервер использую nginx 1.8

```
>     ssl_certificate           "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/ssl.crt";
>     ssl_certificate_key       "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/ssl.key";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сертификаты взял с cloudflare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сертификаты cloudflare работают только в том случае, если сайт доступен через cloudflare. Об этом у них написано.

Кроме того, должен быть подключен промежуточный сертификат самого cloudflare: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-

Его просто надо добавить в ваш файл публичного ключа. Файл публичного ключа - это обычный текстовый файл вида

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE...................
.......................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Файл промежуточного сертификата от cloudflare - тоже текстовый, такого вида:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID...................
.......................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Добавьте промежуточный сертификат в конец вашего файла, чтобы ваш .pem файл принял такой вид:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE...................
.......................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID...................
.......................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Все так и есть, все работает , проблема только у меня с локального ПК , с других ПК или телефонов все ок

Comment: домен делегирован на cloudflare, все записи правильные

Comment: И вы обращаетесь к нему по доменному имени - типа mysite.com? Судя по картинке - да, заметил. ОК, а промежуточный сертификат вы подключили?

Comment: я подключил только то что дали cloudflare
.crt и .key

Comment: Нееее. Я вот об этом https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218689638-What-are-the-root-certificate-authorities-CAs-used-with-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-   дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь , но проблема была в расширении файла сертификата. Странное дело....

Comment: Да не за что, я сам мог бы увидеть .crt в вопросе. Но промежуточный сертификат поставьте. Без него у многих клиентов не работает. Проходил уже.

Comment: Я был бы очень благодарён если бы вы в качестве ответа создали статью о том как правильно установить ssl (cloudflare) A+ на open server (windows) . Я не находил на это ещё ответы. Я уверен что это бы помогло многим.

Comment: Мистическим образом спустя пару часов проблема снова актуально:( , не могли бы вы более подробнее описать как подключить промежуточный сертификат

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в неправильном расширение сертификата . 
Я сохранил как .crt а надо было .pem